# can't use PopOver in Header Menu Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i want create  a header with popover component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Button } from "antd";
const { Header, Popover } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;

const Index = (props) => {
    const content = (
        <menu>
            <Menu.Item>Menu</Menu.Item>
            <SubMenu title="SubMenu">
                <Menu.Item>SubMenuItem</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
        </menu>
    );
    return (
        <Header>
            <div
                className=" float-left text-light"
                style={{ fontSize: "1.4rem" }}
            >
                Shonode
            </div>
            <Menu
                theme="dark"
                mode="horizontal"
                defaultSelectedKeys={["2"]}
                style={{ lineHeight: "64px" }}
            >
                <Menu.Item key="1">nav 1</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2">nav 2</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="3">sda</Menu.Item>

            </Menu>
        </Header>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

this component work but when i paste item 3 with

```js
<Menu.Item key="3">
       <Popover content={content}title="Title" trigger="hover">
        <Button>Hover me</Button>
    </Popover>
</Menu.Item>
```

i get error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to import Popover from Layout which is not a component of Layout

instead of:

```
import { Layout, Menu, Button } from "antd";
const { Header, Popover } = Layout;
```

try:

```
import { Popover, Layout, Menu, Button } from "antd";
const { Header } = Layout;
```